# What's the insert performance like for the WPF Toolkit DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, performance, datagrid, wpftoolkit

Just wondering if anyone knows about what performance is like for the WPF Toolkit DataGrid for inserting rows to the top of the visible area.  I know that ListBox and ListView will recreate all new visuals for all of the rows that are pushed down, which is a major impact on performance; I was wondering if the WPF Toolkit DataGrid does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Toolkit DataGrid should do 'Virtualization', which is what in Microsoft speak is 'reusing WPF objects' (see for example http://www.ytechie.com/2008/09/disabling-wpf-datagrid-virtualization.html).